# What is the minimum size of an image to perform double finger rotation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage, rotation

I am currently try to perform double finger rotation on a image of size 155*75 and its working properly but when i try to perform the same operation on a image 45*25 its not working.So i think the problem may be due to small size and width So what is the minimum size for an image to perform smooth double finger rotation?

Comment: It probably depends on the size of the fingers of the user...

Comment: So what would you think is the most suitable size for any user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple suggest that a finger is approximately 44 points wide on an iOS device screen. Based on that, to fit two of them you'd need 88 points. I'd say 88x88.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm agree with [Amorya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244340/amorya). Few month ago, I've build an app with several button and the buttons size were less than 30px. It became difficult to touch.

Comment: and based on apple website. They suggest approximately 44 point wide on device screen... :)